# Update query with NHibernate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I have couple of questions with update functionaliy using NHibernate

1. I have Customer and location entities with 1:n relationship. Customer has location property. While creating/updating customer entity, I just assigned location property and commited changes.

   ```
   new Location() { Id = ViewModel.LocationId };
   ```

   Is it proper way to do it or do I need to retrieve the location entity from db and attach it again like below

   ```
   newCust.Location = GetlocationfromDB(ViewModel.LocationId);
   ```
2. And how does it work with m:n relationship. I have order and orderitems entities. So, if a newgroup is added/deleted, do I need to check which group is added and get from db and attach it or just groupid will do fine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This isn't the right way to do it - it might work if you have your unsaved-value mapping right for the primary key, but the proper way to do it is to use session.Load(ViewModel.LocationId) see http://ayende.com/blog/3988/nhibernate-the-difference-between-get-load-and-querying-by-id
2. There are a number of ways of dealing with this, but it sounds like you want your relationship to be mapped as a set (to prevent duplicates) rather than a bag.  If you map it as a set and use ISet for the property type of the relationship, the duplicates will be handled for you.  If however you use a bag, you would need to remove duplicates in your own code.  Again, you should be using session.Load to get the group if it's an already existing group.

Comment: Thanks Martin for your reply, it has been helpful. In your first answer, what does "unsaved-value mapping right" mean.

Comment: In your mapping, you can specify an unsaved value for the primary key - NHibernate can then use the value of the primary key to determine if it's a new instance or an existing one